# Get/Set store multiple values for numerous buttons c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to store multiple values from numerous buttons so I can return values of two or more things e.g. if chocolate and vanilla clicked both prices and names can be returned. I will also need to make calculations on the data set later. Whenever I return the data only the most recent values return rather than all of those I have selected.

```
private void VanillaBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                items.Price = 450;
                items.Name = "Vanilla"                             
        }

        private void ChocolateBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                items.Price = 500;
                items.Name = "Chocolate";
        }
```

This is my class, any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
  class Items
{
    private int thePrice;        
    private string theName;


    public int Price

    {
        get                 
        {
            return thePrice;         
        }
        set
        {               
            thePrice = value ;              
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return theName;
        }
        set
        {

            theName = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use database, it will be easier for you.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of whatever was clicked.

```
private List<Items> selectedItems = new List<Items>();
```

So, every time something is clicked, you store the object in the list defined above.

```
private void VanillaBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = new Items();
    newItem.Price = 450;
    newItem.Name = "Vanilla";
    selectedItems.Add(newItem);                             
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help , sorry if I'm being exceedingly dull but where would I put the first code block? in my Items class or in my Main window?

Comment: Main window, so you can track it. And at the end of the process, you will get a complete list of what was clicked.

Comment: when I try to return the values it still only displays one item `sb.Nametxt.Text = items.Name; ` is this where I am going wrong in terms of displaying it. I feel I'm being really stupid

Comment: Ofcourse it will only show the last one. You need to rethink of your proposed solution. If you want to show multiple, you might need some kind of Grid / List View